# Is there a way to prevent specific `enum.Flag` combinations?

Tags: python, enums, enum-flags

If I have an enum class like so:

```py
class TestFlag(enum.Flag):
    A = enum.auto()
    B = enum.auto()
    C = enum.auto()
    D = A | B # valid
```

Is it possible to specify a certain combination, such as, say `TestFlag.C | TestFlag.B` as invalid? In other words, is there a way to ensure that writing `TestFlag.C | TestFlag.B` will raise an Error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `_missing_` method:

```
class TestFlag(enum.Flag):
    A = enum.auto()
    B = enum.auto()
    C = enum.auto()
    D = A | B # valid
    #
    def _missing_(self, value):
        if value in (5, 7):  # list of invalid values
            raise ValueError('%r is not a valid combination' % value)
        return super()._missing_(value)
```

NB: This will not catch invalid choices made during class creation, only operations that occur afterwards.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Would I have to calculate the invalid values by hand or can I somehow use the class itself? like `if value in (TestFlag.A | TestFlag.C,)`?

Comment: @tkott: You would have to calculate them yourself, or use `TestFlag.A.value | TestFlag.C.value`.

Comment: @tkott: How many members do you have, and how complicated are the relationships?

Comment: I only have like 5 members for now, I'm more forward thinking about the fact that I will likely add to them as the software evolves. But if I can use `TestFlag.A.value` type calculations, that's easy! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could add to your TestFlag class:

```
    def __or__(self, other):
        result = super().__or__(other)
        ... throw exception if result has some problem
        return result
```

I'm not sure I'd really recommend it, though.

Comment: Oh right, override the dunder methods. I'd probably need to write one for every binary operation... I forget if there's an overarching binary dunder method....